# C - Function to see if a game reached the "GameOver" point. (2048 copy)

Tags: c, 2048

I'm programing a 2048 game copy in C. But I can't figure out the game over function. I've this struct:

```
typedef struct struct_BLOCO
{
    int valor;
    int cor;
    int x, y;
}   BLOCO;
```

And this is the function I give the board its coordinates:

```
void GiveBlocksCoordinates(BLOCO bloco[16])
{
    int i, j, cont = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
        {
            bloco[cont].x = (j * 8) + X_INI;
            bloco[cont].y = (i * 4) + Y_INI;
            cont++;

        }
    }
}
```

And just put them on screen using a function using the values bloco[i].[x]/[y].
This is my "GameOver" function, in its current state:
PS: The "quant" integer recivies the 16 value. If a block is empty, it has 0 value in it. If is "Game Over", the function return 1.

```
int acabouJogo(BLOCO vec[], int quant)
{
    int i, j, x, y, cont = 0, BlocosOcupados = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < quant; i++)
        if (vec[i].valor != 0)
            BlocosOcupados++;

    if (BlocosOcupados == quant)
    {
        for (x = 0; x != 16; x = x + 4)
        {
            while (cont < 3)
            {
                if (vec[x + cont].valor != vec[(x + cont) + 1].valor)
                    cont++;

                else
                    return 0;
            }
            cont = 0;
        }

        for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            while ( (cont + x) != (12 + x) )
            {
                if (vec[x + cont].valor != vec[(x + cont) + 4].valor)
                    cont = cont + 4;

                else
                    return 0;
            }

            cont = 0;
        }

    }
    else
        return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Can you guys help me?
Sorry for my english.

Thanks.

Comment: So what is your specific question concerning the tags?

Comment: The function "acabouJogo" doens't work. Sometimes it's works, but most of the time, it returns the 1 value but I can still move the blocks. :(